# Как добавить запись в столбец, в котором уже есть записи - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу добавить новые записи в столбец `stb` к уже имеющимся (нужно с учетом имеющегося шв), но ничего толком не получается. В итоге записи или обновляются на новые, либо вообще не заносятся.

Есть такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO post (`id`, `stb`) VALUES
(15471, 'rating 762077|'),
(15485, 'rating 904801|'),
(15613, 'rating 630065|'),
(15757, 'rating 77042|'),
```

Если я так делаю то ругается на `#1062` - Дублирующаяся запись `'15471'` по ключу `'PRIMARY'`
Побывал так но данные просто обновляются удаляя старые

```
INSERT INTO post (`id`, `stb`) VALUES
(15471, 'rating 762077'),
(15485, 'rating 904801'),
(15613, 'rating 630065'),
(15757, 'rating 77042');
on duplicate key update stb =values(stb);
```

Собственно как мне массово добавить записи в столбец `stb`, что бы старые не удалились, может как то с учетом `id` это реализовать можно, так как он постоянно разный.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO post (id, stb) VALUES (15471, 'rating 762077|');
ид далжны битн непавтарауши либи автоматичски тенерирвтх если вам нада эти айды дольнжин
добавить новый таблицу у авто генречия ID
 INSERT INTO post (ID,id, stb) VALUES (null,15471, 'rating 762077|');

Answer (score 0):

Поле `id` в данном случае является первичным ключом, который уникально идентифицирует строку в таблице, по этой причине невозможно добавить новую запись с таким же `id`.
Для того, чтобы перезаписать данные воспользуйтеськомандой [UPDATE](https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/3.4.php)

Comment: Насколько я знаю  UPDATE не заменяет массово записи. Если я ошибаюсь, можно пример реализации с UPDATE, но с таким запросом как у меня.